# Usage of .exe file in framework-dependent asp.net core publish

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, publishing

What does .exe file used for in framework-dependente publish? the project works on IIS and by kestrel with and without this file. So what is the benefit of this file?

Comment: What exe file are you talking about?

Comment: When publish asp.net core project by framework-dependent method, it creates some folders and files. There are {ASSEMBLY NAME}.dll and {ASSEMBLY NAME}.exe files. I mean this {ASSEMBLY NAME}.exe file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that a native executable is not required for framework-dependent deployments, it's still generated by default. You can set the `UseAppHost` property in `.csproj` to false to disable generation of the executable.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>
</PropertyGroup>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999#useapphost